# Angular 2, 4 HTTP (get, post, put, delete, etc...) assign these methods dynamically

Tags: typescript, angular2-http

I want to add http methods dyamicly based on my conditions.

```
var obj = {
  fieldType:"button"
  label:"Submit"
  method:"put" //get, post, delete, etc...
  name:"submit"
  submitUrl:"http://apiurl.com"
  type:"submit"
}
```

How to assign coming object method in http.

```
if( obj.method ){
 this.http.obj.method('www.google.com')
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

EDIT:

I forgot you want it for `angular4`. The request signature is different then:

```
if( obj.method ){
  this.http.request(obj.method, "www.google.com")
  ... 
  }
}
```

In `angular5` the the method can be set in the `RequestOptions`

```
const options = new RequestOptions({

  method: RequestMethod.Post //GET,PUT...

});
```

And the HttpClient has a `request` method for this purpose.

```
this.http.request("www.google.com", options)
     ... 
}
```

Comment: and how to pass my data and request options, not taking more then 2 arguments.
this.http.request(obj.method, `${this.url}`, options)

Comment: It is not clear if you are using the Http or HttpClient, but the options object has body, headers ... properties in both version which you can use.

Comment: can you please check i want to add http methord like this

this.config.forEach((obj) => {

const options = new RequestOptions({
      method: RequestMethod[obj.method],
      params: data
     });
     return this.http.request(`${this.Url}`, options)
      .map( res => res.json() )
      .catch( err => Observable.throw(err.json()))

});